# how to debug TargetInvocationException when deserializing binary file?

Tags: c#, deserialization

I've been getting this error whenever I open a serialized file (binary) created an older version of the application (before I was working here). It looks like this:

Exception:

```
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

Inner expection:

```
InnerException  {"Could not load type 'ENTRY CLASS' from assembly 'PROJECT', Version=1.0.6477.29527, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"ENTRY CLASS"} System.Exception {System.TypeLoadException}
```

Stack Trace:

```
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at PACKAGE.NavigationManager.OpenSavedFile(String filePath) in C:IRL 205
   at NFPA_Checker.NavigationManager.OpenFileDialog_FileOk(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e) in C:\IRL 192
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.OnFileOk(CancelEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.HandleVistaFileOk(IFileDialog dialog)
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.VistaDialogEvents.MS.Internal.AppModel.IFileDialogEvents.OnFileOk(IFileDialog pfd)
```

You just don't seem to get enough info from the error. How do you go about debugging an error like this?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086178/what-could-be-causing-a-system-typeloadexception

Comment: It's because it tries to load the type from assembly in exact version. You can try working around it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012089/7034621